# run_flow complains about getting its minimum three arguments

Tags: python-2.7, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, gmail-api

I'm working on a simple script to send emails via the GMail API, and an old script I found to access their SMTP interface wasn't working.

So I used the following script from their [quickstart page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python) to start first with reading:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#
                                                                                                                                                               
import httplib2
                                                                                                                                                               
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run

CLIENT_SECRET = '.client.json'
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
STORAGE = Storage('gmail.storage')
                                                                                                                                                               
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE)
http = httplib2.Http()
                                                                                                                                                               
credentials = STORAGE.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run(flow, STORAGE, http=http)
                                                                                                                                                                   
http = credentials.authorize(http)
                                                                                                                             
gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
threads = gmail_service.users().threads().list(userId='me').execute()
                                                                                                                                                                   
if threads['threads']:
    for thread in threads['threads']:
        print 'Thread ID: %s' % (thread['id'])
```

Running this gives a `NotImplementedError` as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890146/).

So I imported and called `run_flow` instead of `run`, as I did not install `gflags` to continue. However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: run_flow() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)
```

I understand from the linked question that `argparse` should help. I could add the call to `parser` that that question uses, but I would have no idea what arguments to pass on the command line.

Anyone successfully implemented something with this who could give some help?

Comment: not sure what "they have disabled their SMTP interface" means but I assure you, Google has not disabled their SMTP interface.  :)

Comment: Hmm whoops I was tired when I wrote that :P I think I meant to say an old Python script that connected to Google using libsmtp didn't work any more. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass extra arguments to the command line when using run_flow python.

```
import argparse
...
from oauth2client import tools
...
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow
...
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser])
flags = parser.parse_args()
....
credentials = run_flow(flow, STORAGE, flags, http=http)
```

Then you can run

```
python quickstart.py
```

Comment: This leads me to a 400 error after signing in, but at least it's progress. Looks like I need to match the `redirect_uri`s. Thanks!