# How to add client_secret without using argparser?

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, oauth2client, google-genomics

I want to test Google Genomics. I have a project and I can run [main.py](https://github.com/googlegenomics/getting-started-with-the-api/blob/master/python/main.py) from the [getting started with the api](https://github.com/googlegenomics/getting-started-with-the-api/tree/master/python). But this files hides under the hood of oauth2client how credentials are generated:

```
import argparse
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from collections import Counter
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow

# For these examples, the client id and client secret are command-line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    parents=[tools.argparser])
parser.add_argument('--client_secrets_filename',
                    default='client_secrets.json',
                    help='The filename of a client_secrets.json file from a '
                         'Google "Client ID for native application" that '
                         'has the Genomics API enabled.')
flags = parser.parse_args()

# Authorization
storage = Storage('credentials.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(
    flags.client_secrets_filename,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/genomics',
    message='You need to copy a client_secrets.json file into this directory, '
            'or pass in the --client_secrets_filename option to specify where '
            'one exists. See the README for more help.')
  credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, flags)

# Create a genomics API service
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
```

Can somebody explain me what does the code? How could I convert that into something without argparse?

I tried with other solutions of google-api documentation but the main point is that I don't understand what is being done, so I can't understand what I should do. (I also don't fully understand OAuth2client)
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27037233/2886003) suggest that argparse is mandatory. But [this](http://wescpy.blogspot.com.es/2014/09/simple-google-api-access-from-python.html) other way using google-api-python-client don't use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can use an API key instead, which is more practical when implementing servers - though you would not want to share it with anyone.  Below are two great links that describe how the Oauth2 protocol works in providing access to Google's APIs:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Hope it helps,

Paul

Comment: Thanks Paul, I ended up using the API key with `service = build('genomics', 'v1beta2', developerKey=api_key)`

Comment: Great - you won't regret it :)  Yeah using the API key let's me usually focus more at the analysis or code.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) is to parse command line options.  If you plan on taking arguments at the command line, it's much easier with argparse than without.

If you want to hard-code the arguments (or retrieve them in some other manner), you can just rip out all the `parser` lines, and replace the `flags` variable with the appropriate values (e.g. for the client secrets filename).

Comment: I want to hard-code the argument, but could you please show me how to properly replace the `flags` variable? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Replace `flags.client_secrets_filename` with the hard-coded value.