# How to prevent unit testing from exiting when calling webbrowser.open()?

Tags: python, unit-testing, oauth2client

I am developing unit test for code that use Google oauth2client.tools `run_flow()`. The problem is, this function will call Python `webbrowser.open()`, that will eventually (cmiiw), exit itself by calling `sys.exit()`. Therefore, even if I halt the code execution using `threading.Event.wait()`, it will eventually terminate, without continuing the rest of the unit testing code.

I have read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890146/how-to-get-google-analytics-credentials-without-gflags-using-run-flow-instea) that previously was my problem, but now I still faced with this `webbrowser.open()` issue.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: You probably want to mock `webbrowser.open` so that it doesn't actually run. (You might even want to mock `run_flow`, if it isn't essential to your test that it actually be called.) It's hard to be more specific without seeing the code you want to test and knowing what exactly you are testing.

Comment: try mock `sys.exit` whit some other function?

Comment: I am pretty new to unit testing: especially with mock. But, I really want to get the result of `webbrowser.open()' (that is, creating Picasa token). So I don't think that is a viable option though.